# How can I rate or tag files that aren't images in Windows 7?

Tags: windows

In Windows 7 it is possible to rate images or tag Word-files. Since I'm reading a lot on my computer, I would like to mark PDF-files I've already read. The image-rating-option would be great and so would be the tag option, but other solutions are also very welcome (even adding a small x or so to the details window in the properties). It only needs to be shown in Windows Explorer somehow. I know that it is possible using shells. Unfortunately I'm not a programmer and sure, that I'm not the first one with that 'problem'. Any idea or suggestion anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has built-in tagging capabilities but is limited to office documents. [Here is one of *many* sites that describe this.](http://www.maketecheasier.com/add-tags-in-windows-files-for-quick-and-easy-searching/)

**[TaggedFrog](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-tags-for-your-windows-files-with-taggedfrog/)** - I recently uninstalled this after using it for a couple weeks. Does not integrate into the windows explorer. Interface is clumsy and non-statndard. Adding files and tagging them is tedious and inconvenient.

**[Tag2Find](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tag2find-%E2%80%93-tag-your-windows-files-with-web-like-tags/)** - I used this for a year or so. It's ok, but maybe better polished now. It does integrate with the windows explorer. Definitely better than TaggedFrog.

**[RecentX](http://www.conceptworld.com/RecentX)**

**[TaggTool](http://taggtool.com/)**

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that's unfortunately also not what I'm looking for. I would like to have it integrated into Windows, and to be accessible on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Folder Marker](http://www.foldermarker.com/folder-marker-free.php) to mark folders.

It works on Windows 7 as well as Windows 8 and is also free to use.

You may also try [UserInfoTip](http://www.akslab.com/) to mark files.

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I would like to have it integrated into Windows, and to be accessible on other computers.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't be possible because Windows doesn't have native support for overlay icons on files and folders. And even with a third party tool like UserInfoTip, you can only go upto 15 overlay icons (the limit imposed by Windows). I guess the simplest way to achieve what you want is to categorize files into folders (e.g. watched, read, etc.) and synchronize those folders with all your computers and mobile devices using a service like Dropbox, Google Drive or OneDrive.